# Connecting remotely to Titan Server? [from code]

Tags: scala, titan, gremlin

I want to connect from my code (a scala project) to TitanDB. Code and gremlinserver/titandb are in two different hosts.

In this [example](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan-web-example/blob/master/src/main/java/classesthatrunthings/PopulateDB.java), the connection is made from the same host in which titandb has been installed. 
What if I don't run the code in the same host?

I imagine there could be a configuration file in which I put the hostname and the port. But I can't find anything like it.

So the question is: is connecting remotely, from code, to Titan Server possible?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/cassandra.html#_remote_server_mode)  might be helpful.

You can just connect your application to the local instance of Titan DB. You only have to properly configure the index and the backend storage of each instance of Titan.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure how it may work with scala but with java you can just pass into the factory a configuration file based on what is outlined [here](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/configuration.html). e.g.

```
graph = TitanFactory.open('path/to/configuration.properties')
```

In that configuration you can specify a remote host.

Comment: this is partially true: in `configuration.properties` you put the information of `storage.backend` and `indexing` (example of this  are: `titan-cassandra-es.properties`, which are present as template). 

As @Yoskini, in his answer, stated and referred, you need to install an instance of TitanDB in the same host that runs the code and in **that** `configuration.properties` you add the the hostname (or their IPs)